# DNN - trying to insert background-image in .DnnModule HTML module, and then give client 3 choices to use as HTML modules

Tags: module, background-image, dotnetnuke, skin

My first problem is that I can't even seem to get a full background image to work for individual  modules of type "DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML".  Of course I could give them all the same background-image by targeting the DNN_HTML class, but I need to be able to use different background-images on different HTML modules (I need a green, a blue, and a tan). So I need a way to target the HTML modules being used individually?  Is there a way to do that?  (I am a newb, so please go easy)

Then, the ultimate goal is to have the client able to pick and choose which color module they want to use throughout the site.

Of course I could code an HTML module with the different backgrounds in-line, however, there are various other divs that surround that HTML module, and therefore, the background-image I set in the module using the editor is tiny, and does not cover the whole div.

I'm also not sure if its best to make the client a template with different colored backgrounds they can use already layed out in "bucket" containers for them, but I don't think they could switch the order around could they?

Is there any way at all to accomplish this?  Any help would be really really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really would normally be handled by the Container system within DNN.

I would create 3 different Containers for the colors in question, and then instruct the customer how to choose the Container in the module settings for each of the modules that they want to change the BG for.

Comment: ah.  Ok.  that's actually what I started doing.  Thanks so much!  So I have created one for a HTML div with a green background, now I'm just having problems getting DNN to recognize the new container? I uploaded it, it's called ModuleGreen.aspx, and follow the same exact code as the Standard.aspx, only I just put in some inline-css to make the background green.  However I can't see to find it in my containers drop down?  Do you know what could be happening?  Thankyou!

Comment: ah, maybe because I'm using the same id as Standard - the content-pane ID

Comment: no, seems no matter what I do, my new container isn't being recognized.

Comment: Just to be clear, where are you loading the container? /portals/_default/containers/CONTAINERNAME/ModuleGreen.ascx? 
Be sure you use ASCX not ASPX

Comment: Oh man!  Wow.  I think I need more sleep.  My apologies, I was uploading it as .aspx.  Ugh, what a bonehead move.  Thanks for recognizing that.  :-)